# Create a new column which provides information relating to other rows

Tags: r

How can you create new columns which show (1) how many people each person has in their family under 18, and (2) how many people in family over 18.

[Example starting matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkPTH.png)

I have tried using dplyr spread command, and had a go at a couple of loops but no avail.

Code for the example data frame:

```
    df<- data.frame(FamilyID=c(100,100,100,101,101,102,103,103), 
name=c("Jason", "Masha", "Eamonn", "Leslie", "Dominic", "Carie", 
"William", "Stacy"), 
age=c(14,23,45,6,54,2,58,78), 
sex=c("m","f","m","f","m","f","m","f"))
```

[It should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDhpf.png)

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(FamilyID, ageCateg = case_when(age >18 ~ "Over18", TRUE ~ "Under18")) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% spread(ageCateg, n, fill = 0)`

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work quite right. It creates the new vectors but with the incorrect information...

Comment: According to your question `How can you create new columns which show (1) how many people each person has in their family under 18, and (2) how many people in family over 18.`  The code i showed is grouping by 'FamilyID', and ageCateg by checking the age into two categories, and get the frequency count.  The logic is based on the logic you provided

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You should present the matrices in text presentation (table) rather than as pictures. It is easier to grasp your problem and the whole question is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `mutate` should do the trick:

```
df %>% group_by(FamilyID) %>%
  mutate(over18 = sum(age>18), under18 = sum(age<18))
```

Keep in mind that it's not counting anyone of exactly 18.